# Lucene.net minimum length on search terms

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Does Lucene.NET have a minimum length on search terms?

I'm using Lucene for a project and it seems if I search for anything using 3 characters or less, I get no results.

i.e I have a name like PH_11-11-2013

When I search for `P` `PH` `PH_` I get no results. If I search for `PH_1` I get the result back. (just an example, anything I search for that exists using 1-3 characters is not returned)

I've searched through all the Lucene documentation (for Java) but cannot find anything.

Edit: Analyzer

```
var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_29);
```

Comment: What do your analyzers look like?  I could see this happening when creating ngrams with a minimum gram size of 4, for instance.

Comment: @femtoRgon - I added the analyzer I'm using. I'm new to this Lucene thing so if there's anything specific I should show you to help answer let me know.

Comment: I beleive `StandardAnalyzer` at that version should produce the tokens `ph` and `11-11-2013` (due to special treatment of hyphens with numbers in the token), so it seems like you should get a match on the token `ph`.  Is the same analyzer being applied both when indexing and when querying?

Comment: @femtoRgon yes, same Analyzer used for both. I tried searching on a word i.e the word `money` tried `mon` and got no results. :( `mone` works.

Comment: Strange.  With `StandardAnalyzer`, just searching for `mon` or `mone` neither should get results.  You would need something like `mone*`, which will perform the needed prefix query.  Since you are finding it, it seems like the term `mone` must be present in the index, but I can't imagine why, using `StandardAnalyzer`.  Might be worth taking a look at the index with [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/) (that version of Luke should work well with a Lucene v2.9 index), and seeing exactly what terms have been indexed, and why certain queries match certain document.

Comment: Open the index with LUKE and see what terms have been created.

Comment: http://www.getopt.org/luke/